# UserManager.CreateAsync is not adding user to the database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have this seeder class which is called at the end of the Startup.cs file in the Configure method:

```
public class UserSeeder
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public UserSeeder(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task Seed()
    {
        if (!await _context.Users.AnyAsync())
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = "admin",
                Email = "admin@test.com"
            };
            await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "passwort4admin");
        }
    }
}
```

The code is executed and I even put a try/catch around the method call but no error happens AND no user is inserted into the database!

Why not?

Comment: `CreateAsync` returns a `Task<IdentityResult>`. Check that result, there might be errors.

Comment: What @tmg said. Probably your password is failing the policy check, which you can see when you inspect the identity result.

Comment: Sorry guys, but I did not check that result due to intellisense problem in my vs2017 which is completely broken!

Comment: @Tseng Now that I could fix my VS2017 problems, I could see that I missed an Uppercase character :-)

Comment: @Tseng Good answer, it also helped me.

Comment: In vs2019 no error and no return result, just doesn't seem to do anything. A breakpoint on any code after doesn't get hit :(

Comment: @djack109 See my answer about awaiting

Answer (score 10):

The problem is the complexity of the password. Add capital and numbers and symbols the issue will solve

Comment: That's one possible cause, but it depends on how your password requirements are set up. Simply inspect the return value of `userManager.CreateAsync()` for errors.

Answer (score 4):

Behind the scenes the `UserManager<>` uses a `IUserStore` did you configure this userstore in the startup.cs in the IOC container?

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext, Guid>()
    .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>() //this one provides data storage for user.
    .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
    .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
    .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a space in the user name. It's possible that you have other constraints set up that make the user creation operation illegal.

In most cases, you can obtain explicit information on the exact cause of the error by investigating the message in the returned object from the operation.

```cs
IdentityUser userToBe = ...
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(userToBe);
  if(!result.Succeeded)
    foreach(IdentityError error in result.Errors)
      Console.WriteLine($"Oops! {error.Description} ({error.Code}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to set "Username", it cannot be empty.
I set UserName=userEmail and it works

Answer (score 0):

For those who cannot even get a `result` to inspect: Make sure you `await` your seeder method in `Program.cs`, otherwise the method may fail and not return:

```
using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope()
await scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserSeeder>().Seed();
```

Then it will be ready for `app.Run();`